# Cargar una imagen con django 2.0

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, django-models

Necesito cargar una imagen en el sitio de administración o en otra página html, tengo un modelo el cual tiene un atributo ImageField, necesito una vez que se le asigne una imagen poder visualizarla. Gracias de antemano a cualquier ayuda

Comment: Lo más facil es utilizar ModelForms https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/forms/modelforms/  si quieres más ayudan pon código para ver que por lo menos lo has intentado

Answer (score 1):

Primero que todo tienes que crear un directorio llamado media en la raíz de tu proyecto, o sea donde están todas tus apps y el archivo manage.py

Luego de eso tienes que ir al archivo settings y al final del todo pon las siguientes líneas:

```
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR,"media")
```

Dentro de la carpeta media debes crear otro directorio para guardar las imágenes del modelo. Le puedes poner el nombre de la app donde tienes el modelo. Si tu app se llama proyectos, creas el directorio proyectos en media. O sea /media/proyectos.

A continuación tu campo Imagafield lo dejas así:

```
image = models.ImageField(verbose_name="Imagen", upload_to="proyectos")
```

Como te puedes dar cuenta, el atributo upload_to apunta al directorio que crearás en /media

Espero te sirva.
Saludos

Haciendo todo esto, podrás ver la imagen en el panel de administración.

Comment: Gracias, lo pruebo y te comento

Comment: Funcionó al final ?

Comment: Si ya funciona, gracias

Comment: Me alegro mucho haberte ayudado. Si puedes marca la respuesta como útil si es que lo fue. Saludos!